# PPTP Disconnects

Tags: connection-issues, vpn

I am using the built in PPTP client on my 2.3 phone and 3.0.1 tablet, to connect to the same PPTP gateway. Neither will stay connected for longer than about 5 minutes, maximum.

My phone uses it's 3g connection. My table is Wifi only. I have a laptop that will stay connected, that connects via my home Wifi. I also have a wired desktop at home, that also stays connected. So it's just the two Android device, via 3G and Wifi, neither stay connected.

Are the better PPTP clients out there? Or something I can tune on my devices perhaps? They both have the maximum power settings for wifi already configured. The tablet is rooted, if that provides me with any other options?